# do while loops can't have two cin statements?

Tags: c++, cin, do-while

I'm just following a simple c++ tutorial on do/while loops and i seem to have copied exactly what was written in the tutorial but i'm not yielding the same results. This is my code:

```
int main()
{
    int c=0;
    int i=0;
    int str;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter a num: \n";
        cin >> i;
        c = c + i;
        cout << "Do you wan't to enter another num? y/n: \n";
        cin >> str;

    } while (c < 15);

    cout << "The sum of the numbers are: " << c << endl;


    system("pause");
    return (0);
}
```

Right now, after 1 iteration, the loop just runs without asking for my inputs again and only calculating the sum with my first initial input for i.
However if i remove the second pair of cout/cin statements, the program works fine..

can someone spot my error please? thank you!

Comment: What tutorial is this? It completely ignores the content of the `y/n` answer, and only iterates while the total sum is less than 15

Comment: I believe `str` should be type of `std::string`.

Comment: @maverik, more like `char` if it's just y/n.

Comment: @chris: sure. It even can be left as an `int` but it looks strange for me.

Comment: ah.. sorry, the original tutorial had while (str == 'y') as the terminating criteria but even when i entered 'y' after the first iteration ,it just exits the whole loop and prints my first input i as the sum..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change

```
int str;
```

to

```
char str;
```

Your loop works as you seem to intend (tested in Visual Studio 2010).
Although, you should also probably check for `str == 'n'`, since they told you that they were done.

Answer (score 4):

After you read the string with your `cin >> str;`, there's still a new-line sitting in the input buffer. When you execute `cin >> i;` in the next iteration, it reads the newline as if you just pressed <kbd>enter</kbd> without entering a number, so it doesn't wait for you to enter anything.

The usual cure is to put something like `cin.ignore(100, '\n');` after you read the string. The `100` is more or less arbitrary -- it just limits the number of characters it'll skip.

Comment: One can always use `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` instead of `100` if they want to skip everything till a newline.

Comment: @Fanael: You can, and at times it makes sense. That isn't nearly as often as many people seem to think though -- if you're really getting a *lot* of unexpected input, it generally makes more sense to stop and tell the user about the problem than waste a long time consuming gargantuan amounts of input when there's obviously a problem.

Answer (score 1):

> ...and only calculating the sum with my first initial input for i...

This is an expected behavior, because you are just reading the `str` and not using it. If you enter `i >= 15` then loop must break, otherwise continues.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted this thing

In this case total sum `c` will be less than 15 and continue to sum if user inputs y.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int c=0;
    int i=0;
    char str;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter a num: \n";
        cin >> i;
        c = c + i;
        cout << "Do you wan't to enter another num? y/n: \n";
        cin >> str;

    } while (c < 15 && str=='y');

    cout << "The sum of the numbers are: " << c << endl;
    return 0;
}
```